# How to join 2 tables & display them correctly?

Tags: php, mysql, join, mybb

http://img293.imageshack.us/img293/857/tablez.jpg
Here is a picture of the 2 tables.

The **mybb_users** table is the table that has the users that signed up for the forum.

The **mybb_userfields** is the table that contain custom profile field data that they are able to customize & change in their profile.

Now, all I want to do is display all users in rows with the custom profile field data that they provided in their profile(which is in the **mybb_userfields** table)

How can I display these fields correctly together?

---

For instance, p0gz is a male,lives in AZ,he owns a 360,does not know his bandwidth & Flip Side Phoenix is his team.
How can it just be like "p0gz-male-az-360-dont know-flipside phoenix" in a row~???

Answer (score 4):

This looks for me like an ordinary `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT * FROM mybb_users
  LEFT JOIN mybb_userfields
    ON (mybb_users.uid = mybb_userfields.ufid)
WHERE username = 'p0gz'
```

This should display every row of the user `p0gz`

Comment: It came out with
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/rootkbc1/public_html/mujak/test/test2.php on line 117

Comment: uhm, try this code in phpMyAdmins SQL function. If you get a result, something must be wrong with your php code

Comment: I ran it in phpmyadmins sql function and it came out with Unknown column 'mybb_users.id' in 'on clause'

Comment: Ooook :D the problem is that I have written `id` and it isn't `id` its `uid`. I'll edit my code, and after that, the query should work correctly. So the error was that I've tried to fetch a not existing column. Sorry

Comment: It worked~!! I changed it from id to uid & it is working exactly as expected~!! THANK YOU~!!!!!!!!!!